# Posso utilizar as tags header/footer dentro da tag main/section?

Tags: html, html5, semântica

Eu gostaria de saber se pode, dentro do elemento `<main>`, ou `<section>`, colocar as *tags* `<header>` e `<footer>`.

Por exemplo:

```
<section>
   <header>topo da section</header>
      conteudo da section
   <footer>rodape da section</footer>
</section>
```

ou

```
<main>
  <header>topo da section</header>
    conteudo da tag main
  <footer>rodape da section</footer>
</main>
```

dessa forma está correto??

Answer (score 7):

Sim, é permitido.

Conforme a especificação W3C, tanto o elemento [`<section>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-section-element) quanto o [`<main>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) permitem como conteúdo os elementos classificados como [*flow content*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#flow-content), que incluem os elementos `<header>` e `<footer>`.

Por exemplo, uma publicação em um blog:

```
<main>
    <header>
        <h1>Minha espetacular publicação<h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <p>Ok, não é tão espetacular assim</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <time datetime="2018-08-28 20:00">Publicado em 2018-08-28 20:00</time>
    </footer>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

Vamos lá, uma seção é como se pertencesse ao tronco de uma pessoa, o header a cabeça e footer fosse os pés, caso coloque o footer dentro de uma section os pés ficariam no estomago porém ainda seria possível usá-lo só que ficaria estranho(kkk). Já quando se trata do main ele não pode ser 'filho' desses elementos.

Comment: entendi...então, apenas o mais não pode ser filho, porém, ele pode ter filhos...é isso então, né??? obrigado galera!! vocês são 10!